# Android WebView with css and javascript

Tags: android, android-webview

Many of the answers I've been seeing here are 6+ years old so I was wondering if I could get a more recent answer as they haven't been working for me.  I have an html file `file.html` which contains a

```
<LINK href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

for the CSS and the following for the javascript:

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

`file.html`, `stylesheet.css` and `myscript.js` are all stored in `app/assets/Content/`

So I am trying to run it with:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.event_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///assets/Content/file.html");
```

However, the WebView is showing the error:

> Webpage not available:  The webpage at
>   file:///assets/Content/file.html could not be loaded because
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I have also considered using loadDataWithBaseURL but this requires the data field to contain all of the html which is too big of a file to hardcode.
Does anybody know how I could use html+css+javascript for a WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI for `asset` folder is incorrect. Change `asset` to `android_asset`. As follows:

`webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");`

Comment: So the directory structure can stay the same, `/ap/android/assets/Content/file.html` but the line in Java will be `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content/event_progress_thermometer.html");`?

EDIT:  Yep, this worked!

Comment: How would I then call a function in my javascript file `myscript.js` from java?

Comment: You can use `webView.evaluateJavascript("<functionname>()", null)` to call JS method.